# How to custom or display modebar in plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I would like to custom the modebar (on top right) so as to keep just "zoom","pan","box select","zoom in" and "zoom out". If it's not possible, I prefer display the modebar.

Here graph and code :
[image]

```
x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
xy <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
example <- ggplot(data = xy,aes(x = x,y = y))+geom_line()
ggplotly(example)
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Oh... Because some options doesn't work or are inappropriates so I can't keep it. But if I don't have choices so be it... Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using your example:

```
x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
xy <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
example <- ggplot(data = xy,aes(x = x,y = y))+geom_line()

ggplotly(example) %>% config(displaylogo = FALSE,
modeBarButtonsToRemove = list(
    'sendDataToCloud',
    'toImage',
    'autoScale2d',
    'resetScale2d',
    'hoverClosestCartesian',
    'hoverCompareCartesian'
))
```

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxpqh.png)

Other options include: 'zoom2d','pan2d','select2d','lasso2d','zoomIn2d', and 'zoomOut2d'

Comment: any idea why this isn't working anymore? i've updated packages a few times sine your post and now the mode bar buttons are back!

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the buttons to remove, instead of making a list.

The following works for me:

```
x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
xy <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))
example <- ggplot(data = xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line()

ggplotly(example) %>% config(displaylogo = FALSE,
modeBarButtonsToRemove = c(
    'sendDataToCloud',
    'toImage',
    'autoScale2d',
    'resetScale2d',
    'hoverClosestCartesian',
    'hoverCompareCartesian'
))
```