# How to add a modebar button in plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to create custom modebar buttons for heatmap graphs (e.g., box selection, lasso selection). It is possible to edit specific Mode Bar buttons through the [config](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js) argument [descriptions](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/modebar/buttons.js), but I don't know how to implement this javascript code to add buttons in R.

You can set dragmode to "select":

```
p = plot_ly(z = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10), type = "heatmap") %>%
layout(dragmode =  "select")
```

which gives the desired behavior, but if you select any other tools, you can’t get back to the select tool.

Comment: have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437808/how-to-custom-or-display-modebar-in-plotly

Comment: They have just removed buttons, it's pretty straightforward. What I want is to add these box select or lasso select buttons.